# What is the difference between a method, an approach, a technique, and a strategy in the case of STEM research?

Tags: research-process, stem

What is the difference between a method, an approach, a technique, and a strategy in the case of STEM research?

For example:

> These algorithms can be grouped into three broad categories:
> (i) methods that assign SSE directly from the local geometric parameters derived from C positions.
> (ii) approaches directly using C coordinates of short structural fragments and comparing them to structural fragments extracted from known protein structures.
> (iii) methods that use Machine Learning (ML) methods to infer SSE.

The above text seems to be mixing up methods and approaches.

How do I know which one is a method and which one is an approach and why?

Also, plz shed some light on technique and strategy.

Comment: The author of the example seems to be using methods and approaches as synonyms. Rewrite   (ii) as "methods directly ..." The meaning doesn't really change. And using the other terms seems to work just as well. "(i) strategies that assign...

Comment: This is an English language usage question. Those terms are not rigorously defined.

Comment: This is a poorly written question. What do you want us to give you that a dictionary can’t? Why is there no citation for your quote? And if you are looking for rigorous use of human language, why do you say “plz”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a clear enough distinction between the terms that would result in technical definitions of each. Different authors might choose one term rather than another. Other authors might have some distinctions in their own work.

But "technique" might seem to be a bit more specific than "strategy" and almost indistinguishable from "method".

On the other hand, approach and strategy might seem to be a bit less specific than the other. You might refine an approach into a technique.

But, this seems to be a case, generally, of too close to call. Language is messy. English especially as it has had many roots and influences.

A possible, but arguable, listing from least to most specific might be something like approach > strategy > method > technique. Just sort of cogitating though.